# Windows 10 force user logoff

Tags: windows-10, login, time

Is there a program in Windows 10 or other Windows that can manage the user's logon hours (force logoff after specific time)? I know that Windows 10 and below has it built in, but the problem is that I have to create an account for them in order to specify their login times which is hassle because a lot of people uses the computer in the house. A time scheduler for the local user is what I need.

Comment: Can't you use the guest account for this?

Comment: In windows 10 I can only create a local user. It can only be done manually

Comment: [4 Ways to Enable and Disable Built-in Guest on Windows 10](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-enable-and-disable-built-in-guest-on-windows-10.html)

Comment: By the way what is the difference between standard user and guest ?

Comment: A guest account is an account for users who don't have a permanent account on your computer or domain. It allows people to use your computer without having access to your personal files. People using the guest account can't install software or hardware, change settings, or create a password.

You have to turn on the guest account before it can be used.

Comment: Ok but the problem is still there, I cannot specify a time then force the account to loggoff

Comment: Unfortunately, questions which ask for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly and attract subjective answers. For advice on how to ask a question which may require recommending software, see [this Meta Super User post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/).

Comment: @Shulz Scheduled Task running `shutdown /l /t0` ?

Comment: Use Group Policy to do this. There's a policy to auto-logoff when logoff hours expire, and you can specify logon hours as well. You could try experimenting with loopback processing maybe...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of software comes that don't need any accounts ,all you have to do is give a specific time.

Try this link : http://download.cnet.com/Wise-Auto-Shutdown/3000-2084_4-75755206.html

Answer (score -1):

Is this for your family? Reason I ask is that you could utilize the "Windows Family Safety site to manage their screen time.